# Azure Active Directory PIM with guest users

Tags: azure-active-directory, passport-azure-ad

We have company giving us managed support for our azure subscription?

1. Can we enable MFA for them as well i.e for guest accounts?
2. Is AzureAD PIM works for external users i.e guest accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. It's best practice to [enforce MFA for guest users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-tutorial-require-mfa).
2. Yes, you can [assign PIM roles for guest users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-configure) and use PIM for assigning access to Azure resources.